# HttpPost returning a corrupt file

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-web-api2

Initially I was returning an .xlsx file through HttpGet method, but, now I have to pass really big array of Ids to the server to get that file. I have tried to increase the maxUrlLength to 2097151 and my web config  contains

```
 <security>
          <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits
                maxAllowedContentLength="30000000"
                maxUrl="2097151"
                maxQueryString="2097151"/>
          </requestFiltering>
        </security>
```

Due to large size of request, I've chosen to use HttpPost. My code looks like:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage result = new System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK);
result.Content = response;
            result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition =
            new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
            {
                FileName = fileName
            };
result.Content.Headers.ContentType =
                new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
            result.Content.Headers.Add("FileName", fileName);
            return result;
```

The file returned gives the following error;

We found a problem with some content in xxx.xlsx. Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can? If you trust the source of this workbook, click yes.
If I click yes then:

Excel cannot open the file xxx.xlsx because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file.

I'm using Angular2 at front end.

```
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        return this._http.post(this.config.apiEndpoint + encodeURI(url), param, options).finally(() => {
            if (showSpinner) { this.removeSpinner(); }
        });
```

What should be the remedy?

Comment: post the error message as text not picture

Comment: Error message is in text now @Rahul

Comment: Is the xlsx file being generated dynamically? If so, how?

Comment: Yes I'm creating it dynamically using ExcelWorksheet and returning MemoryStream